# How to space out xticks in matplotlib, pyplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

As you can see, the xticks are very crowded and cannot be read. How do I space them out better on matplotlib? Any tips?  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QpAe.png)

Comment: @cottontail same result unfortunately :(

Comment: Please create a [reprex].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what is happening is that your x-axis values aren't datetime objects. If you turn them into datetime objects, it should automatically space them correctly.